# Construct parameters in AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, parameters, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to !Ref from one parameter to another in CloudFormation. I tried several things but it just doesn't seem to work.

```
UserID:
    Description: "Enter the user ID provided by your organization"
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern : ".+"   
Date:
    Description: "Enter the Date in YYYYMMDD format"
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern : ".+"   
AccountName:
```

I would like to contruct AccountName using UserID and Date entered by the user. Can someone please help?

Suppose user enters abcd01 and 20201124 --> I want the account name to be automatically abcd01-20201124

Answer (score 1):

Instead of another [`Parameter`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html), use [`Sub`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) wherever you need that combined value:

```yaml
!Sub ${UserID}-${Date}
```